# findViewByID not work in tab layout

Tags: android, fragment, android-tablayout

i use tab layout matching this tutorial:

[tab layout tutorial androidhive](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

It works fine, but when I add a button to fragment_one.xml , i cant use setOnClickListener for this button Because findViewById not work in MainActivity.java

the MainActivity bellow code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

the app stopped with this error:
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener' on a null object reference

Where should the button be defined and setOnClickListener?

Comment: where is the Button? show ur layout(s)

Comment: You have to find the button inside fragment class and set onclick listener for it not in activity

Comment: button is in the fragment_one.xml @DroiDev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though a fragment is hosted by an activity, it has its own layout (which is *contained* in the activity's layout) and therefore you'll have to define the fragment's view in its `java class`.

In most cases, a fragment would have its own Java class for you to manage and manipulate it, so in your case, it should look like this:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        Button button=view.findViewById(R.id.myButtonInFragment);
        return view;
    }

}
```

---

If you'd like to access this button from its parent activity, you can achieve it by making the button **public**:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

   public Button button;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        button=view.findViewById(R.id.myButtonInFragment);
        return view;
    }
}
```

and then, access it using the fragment's instance in your `activity`:

```
OneFragment myFragment=new OneFragment();
```

After you have attached the fragment to the activity, you can use:

```
myFragment.button.setClickEnabled(false);
```

However, accessing fragment's children outside of the fragment is not recommended, and you should avoid it if you can.

Comment: What is the best way to access the button in other classes?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    Fragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragment = new Fragment();


        View view = fragment.getView();
        if (view !=null) {
             view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        }
    }
}
```